# Can this CSS class written in shorter, better way?

Tags: class, css

Can you write this CSS class in a shorter way? Thank you.

```
.MessageTitle a, .MessageTitle a:visited, .MessageTitle a:active, .MessageTitle a:hover,.MessageSender a, .MessageSender a:visited, .MessageSender a:active, .MessageSender a:hover
{
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
     display:block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: Black;
    line-height:30px;    
}

.MessageTitle a:active, .MessageTitle a:hover,.MessageSender a:active, .MessageSender a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.MessageTitle a,
.MessageSender a
{   text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display:block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: Black;
    line-height:30px;    
}

.MessageTitle a:active,
.MessageTitle a:hover,
.MessageSender a:active,
.MessageSender a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.MessageSender a:visited,
.MessageSender a:visited
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You should probably also include `:focus`.  I would also use `:link`.

In practice, for proper [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) brevity, simplicity and UX consistency, I would declare all these styles globally on the bare `a` selector, so more like this:

```
a:link
{   text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    color: Black }

a:active,
a:hover,
a:focus
{   text-decoration: underline}

a:visited
{   text-decoration: none}

.MessageTitle a,
.MessageSender a
{   
    display:block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:30px;    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could apply a single class to the anchor so you aren't defining the same groups twice.

```
.messageLink, .messageLink:visited {
    color: #000;
    display:block;
    line-height:30px;
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.messageLink:active, .messageLink:hover { text-decoration:underline; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The really short way would be to look at Less CSS.
www.lesscss.org